# Menu not working on IE

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, gradient

I hope you will be able to help me with this problem.
It only shows a dark grey background so the  gradient isn't working. I tried fixing it myself but no luck. thanks for any help. 
Here is the code below.

```
#menu{
    width: 980px;

margin-right:0;
margin-top:0;
margin-bottom:0;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    list-style: none;  
    background: #111;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #111); 
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, 

#111),color-stop(1, #444)); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #111);    
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
}

#menu li{
    float: left;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    position: relative;
}

#menu a{
    float: left;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 0 25px;
    color: #999;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: bold 12px/25px Arial, Helvetica;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
}

#menu li:hover > a{
    color: #fafafa;
}

*html #menu li a:hover{ /* IE6 */
    color: #fafafa;
}

#menu li:hover > ul{
    display: block;
}



#menu ul li{
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;  
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111111, 0 2px 0 #777777;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111111, 0 2px 0 #777777;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111111, 0 2px 0 #777777;
}

#menu ul li:last-child{   
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;    
}

#menu ul a{    
    padding: 10px;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 1;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: none;
    text-transform: none;
}

*html #menu ul a{ /* IE6 */   
    height: 10px;
    width: 150px;
}

*:first-child+html #menu ul a{ /* IE7 */    
    height: 10px;
    width: 150px;
}

#menu ul a:hover{
        background: #0186ba;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);    
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#04acec), to

(#0186ba));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);

    background: linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);

}

#menu ul li:first-child a{
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

#menu ul li:first-child a:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    top: -8px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #444;
}

#menu ul li:first-child a:hover:after{
    border-bottom-color: #04acec; 
}

#menu ul li:last-child a{
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

/* Clear floated elements */
#menu:after{
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}

* html #menu             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html #menu { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */
```

Comment: CSS alone isn't enough information to be able to help. Make a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with a basic example of the problem. Help us help you! http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XmlXU4uK5rA

Answer (score 0):

Like Anando said, use a CSS3 gradient generator like http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/,  which will generate code compatible with all browsers.

If the problem is with `IE6-8`, you need to add something like this to your CSS:

```
#menu{    
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#444',
     endColorstr='#111',GradientType=1 ); 
}
```

For IE9, which doesn't support CSS3 gradients, you need to use an SVG gradient. Put in your CSS something like:

```
#menu{ 
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}
```

And you need to add a "gradient" class to all your elements that have a gradient, and add the following override to your HTML to complete the IE9 support:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <style type="text/css">
    .gradient {
       filter: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```